# How do I access $_SESSION variables after Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page where people can login and their login request is sent with jQuery's $.ajax to a processing page. On that page all of the errors collected during the login attempt are stored in $_SESSION['error'].

How can I access this variable to alert users of the errors after the attempt is made. I know how to access a session variale, I mean how do I access a php variable without reloading the page. The only way I currently am aware of is to inject them on page load, but there must be some way to access them with JavaScript after they have changed due to an Ajax request.

Comment: You return them to the ajax call by echoing whatever you need to return.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: Session state only exists on the server; Javascript only exists on the client.  The only way to communicate between them is to include data in the response to the AJAX call.

Comment: The best way to find an example and learn how it works is by reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and trying it out yourself

Comment: @adeneo it took goddamn forever but finally I found enough random crap on the internet and read enough FireBug error messages to get it working. Ultimately your answer of echo it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot directly access the PHP `$_SESSION[]` array from JavaScript. This is by design, because one of the major points of using a Session, is that the data is saved on the server side, unmodifiable by the end user, and therefore your Javascript.

What you could do however, is include the error list in your ajax response. Chances are you are doing an ajax request that returns a 'json' type format. Just include your error list in your json returned, and use the JavaScript to display them. I recommend not sharing the entire `$_SESSION` array, since it could give away some key information about the interworkings of your PHP.

Also, if you are not currently doing an ajax request that expects json, back, then consider switching it up so that you are expecting and returning json. You can provide much more hidden data this way, instead of just some HTML or text.

Hope this helps